# I cannot get ListActivity to display

Tags: android

App doesnt crash but i just get a blank page.... heres code tell me if you need more, sorry if im doing this wrong Seems I have to add more info and I really dont know what to add could be I have wrong imports or somthing?:

```
package com.eric.thebasics;




import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;


public class TutorialTwo extends ListActivity {

String classNames[] = {"main", "menu", "Sweet", "TutorialOne"};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1));
}

protected void onListItemClick(ListView lv, View v, int position, long id){
    super.onListItemClick(lv, v, position, id);
    String openClass = classNames[position];
    try{
        Class selected = Class.forName("com.eric.thebasics." + openClass);
        Intent selectedIntent = new Intent(this,selected);
        startActivity(selectedIntent);
    }catch (ClassNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

here's button code:

```
tut2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            buttonSound.start();
            startActivity(new Intent("com.eric.thebasics.TUTORIALTWO"));
```

and here is manifest:

```
<activity
        android:name=".TutorialTwo"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.eric.thebasics.TUTORIALTWO" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
 setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, classNames));
```

you never added your classNames into the ArrayAdapter

Answer (score 1):

Just use the .class reference which is typesafe, instead of the String. Try

```
startActivity(new Intent(ActivityLaunchingFrom.this, TutorialTwo.class))
```

replace ActivityLaunchingFrom with the actual name of the Activity your starting the other one from. You have to use the "qualified this" syntax because otherwise `this` refers to the `onClickListener`.

And if you really want the classes in the array, then just make it an array of classes like

```
    Class[] classes = {Main.class, Menu.class, TutorialTwo.class};
```

Comment: This is helpful, but not what his problem is. He is seeing only a blank screen because there is nothing in his ArrayAdapter

Answer (score 0):

maybe TutorialTwo in the Intent is all capitalized, the name isnt

```
 tut2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        buttonSound.start();
        startActivity(new Intent("com.eric.thebasics.TutorialTwo"));
```

Comment: That refers to the manifest so it should be all caps? I tryed anyway and it causes a crash.

Comment: sorry, go with the guy that said you didnt populate your adapter